# Swift: Need to refactor incrementing a lot of integers based on which button is pushed

Tags: swift, uibutton, integer, increment, ibaction

I have quite a few integers that need to be incremented by one when certain buttons are pushed. Here is the short version on how I am achieving this.

```
@IBAction func incrementAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        switch sender.tag {
        case 0:
            redCount += 1
        case 1:
            blueCount += 1
        case 2:
            greenCount += 1
        default:
            ()
        }
    }
```

This works, but I don't want the list of switch cases getting too long. Also, I believe it is somewhat violating `DRY` concept.

I tried resolving this by doing the following.

```
let colorArray = [redCount, blueCount, greenCount]
var colorCount = colorArray[sender.tag]
colorCount += 1
```

However, the integers in the array aren't being updated individually.

Comment: Don’t have separate variables. Just use an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary seems to be the most appropriate data structure for the job. And rather than using a tag to identify a view, you should add a `Color` to it, and reference that directly.

```
import AppKit

enum Colour: CaseIterable { case red, green, blue }

class MyColouredButton: UIButton {
    var colour: Colour = .red // some default value, change this.
}

class MyVC: UIViewController {
    var colourCounts = [Colour: Int]()

    @IBAction func incrementAction(_ sender: MyColouredButton) {
        colourCounts[sender.colour, default: 0] += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
enum Color: Int {
    case red = 0
    case blue = 1
    case green = 2
}


var colors: [Color : Int] = [.red : 0, .green : 0, .blue : 0]


func incrementColorCount(tag: Int) {

    guard let color = Color(rawValue: tag), let colorCount = colors[color] else {
        print("Invalid color")
        return
    }
    colors[color] = colorCount + 1
}

// Test
incrementColorCount(tag: 0)
incrementColorCount(tag: 1)

colors.forEach {
    print("Color: \($0.key) has been hit \($0.value) times")
}

//Color: red has been hit 1 times
//Color: green has been hit 0 times
//Color: blue has been hit 1 times
```